# PHP dirname() drops entire path

Tags: php, path, directory, dirname

I have a variable $path which contains the full path to a file on a Windows network (e.g. `R:\somedir\otherdir\lastdir\some.file.ext`)

when I use:

```
    $location = dirname($path);
```

here, `$location` only records the value `.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the manual: `Since PHP 4.3.0, you will often get a slash or a dot back from dirname() in situations where the older functionality would have given you the empty string.` i suggest reading the notes here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: Thanks I have read this entry, $path contains slashes so I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: it contains backslashes, not slashes

Comment: Ok I have managed to get around this with the following code: $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path);
$location = dirname($path);          Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong slash.
Instead of using the backslash `\` use the normal slash `/`

> A file path and a URI are different. \ is correct in a Windows file
>   path and / is correct in a URI.
>
> So this file path: C:\Documents\Foo translates to this URI:
>   file:///C:/Documents/Foo

From the php documentation:

> If there are no slashes in path, a dot ('.') is returned, indicating
>   the current directory. Otherwise, the returned string is path with any
>   trailing /component removed.

**This means that the problem is that your slashes are wrong.**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a forwardslash '/'.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this though and it does not strip the filename from the end.

Comment: he's using backslashes - that is a slash (\ is a blackslash)

Comment: Is there anyway to change slashes to backslashes in a string? The string is generated by an <input type="file"> tag in an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\` with `/` and try again